# In React, how to divert the scrolling to another element?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, scroll, scrollbar

My APP has 3 divs: side, middle, and right.

The middle section will contain the content list of arbitrary number of items. It is set to the length of the `vh`. Thus, it will need to scroll when too many items are present.

The problem is when the user scroll over the side or right divs, nothing happens.

To solve, the problem, all scrolling should be diverted to the middle div, no matter where the pointer is hovering.

How can this be done in React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this in React is fairly straightforward. Here is a functional component I created that is working as desired:

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./Content.css";

const Content = (props) => {
  
  const [contentHover, setContentHover] = useState(false);
  const contentRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {

    const handleScrolling = (event) => {
      if(contentRef !== null) {
        if(contentHover === false) {
          contentRef.current.scrollTop += event.deltaY;
        }
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("wheel", handleScrolling);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("wheel", handleScrolling);
    }
  })

  return (
    <div 
      className="content" 
      ref={contentRef}
      onMouseEnter={ () => { setContentHover(true) }}
      onMouseLeave={ () => { setContentHover(false) }}
    >
      {/* YOUR LIST OF CONTENT OR WHATEVER */}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Content;
```

**Explanation**

There are three things that make this solution work.

First, I used [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to get access to the element that I want to scroll. In my example, this is the `div` with the class `content`. In your case it will be your middle div. This is important because doing this gives access to the element's [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) property. Using `scrollTop` we can set the position of the element's scroll bar.

Second, I added state called `contentHover` using [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). I toggle its value between `true` and `false` using the `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeve` event handlers on `div` I want to scroll. When the mouse enters my div `contentHover` becomes `true`. When it leaves it becomes `false`. This is important because we don't want to double scroll the element i.e. make it scroll twice as fast. We will check if `contentHover` is false, meaning the mouse is not in the element we want to scroll, before applying our custom scroll function.

Finally, the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook. I added an event listener for the `wheel` event. When the `wheel` event is fired, the event object passed to the `handleScrolling` function contains a [`deltaY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/deltaY) property. Inside `handleScrolling` I add `deltaY` to the ref element's `scrollTop` property to get a similar result as scrolling normally. Finally, I remove the event listener in `useEffect`'s [clean up function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup).

In summary, we aren't necessarily "diverting" scrolling to another element. Instead, we listen for the wheel event, keep a reference to the element we want to scroll, and then update that element's scrollTop whenever the event is fired.

Hope this helped you in some way!

Comment: Functionally, it worked. But the scrolling isn't smooth like if you scrolled naturally. Is there a fix to make it smooth as well?

Answer (score 1):

Going by the first solution, I solved the smooth scroll problem by changing the code to this:

```
const handleScrolling = (event) => {
      if (contentRef !== null) {
        if (contentHover === false) {
          contentRef.current.scrollTo({
            top: contentRef.current.scrollTop + event.deltaY,
            behavior: "smooth",
          });
        }
      }
    };
```